# catching server response

Tags: java, android, visual-studio, c#-4.0, xamarin.android

I am using Webview to implement browser capabilities in my project. Lets say someone searches for download.com in google, searches for a software (in download.com), and then clicks on the download link. A request will be made to the server which will respond back with the respective download file. Now is there any way I can catch the server response so that I can send it to some other app (lets say, to a download manager)? Note that I don't know when will the user click on the download link.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebView exposes a [Download](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=E%3aAndroid.Webkit.WebView.Download) event that you could hook into to catch when something is going to be downloaded:

```
webView.Download += (sender, args) =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(args.Url);
                    };
```

Alternatively, you could create your own implementation of an [IDownloadListener](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=T%3aAndroid.Webkit.IDownloadListener):

```
public class MyDownloadListener : Java.Lang.Object, IDownloadListener
{
    public void OnDownloadStart(string url, string userAgent, string contentDisposition, string mimetype, long contentLength)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(url);
    }
}
```

and provide that to the WebView:

```
var listener = new MyDownloadListener();
webView.SetDownloadListener(listener);
```